# Macros taking operators as arguments

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am working on a projet in C, and I was wondering if we could do this in some way:

```
#define OPERATION(operator) 1 (operator) 3
```

and use it like that

```
// Some code (those are exemples)
a = OPERATION(+);
a = OPERATION(==);
// Some more code
```

Thank you for the answers

The code I'm working on, tries to improve this code to do operations over matrix. I'm still working on it. In the future, I intended to use Duff's device on the outside for too.

```
#define MATRIX_OPERATION(ans,a,b,width,height,eqOp,op)   int y, n, orig = ((height) + 9) / 10, swControl = (height)%10; \
 for(int x=0; x<(width); x++){ \
 y = 0; \
 n = orig; \
 switch (swControl){ \
    case 0: do { (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 9: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 8: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 7: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 6: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 5: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 4: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 3: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 2: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
    case 1: (ans) (eqOp) (b) (op) (a); \
        } while (--n); \
}}
```

Comment: And that is shorter than `1 + 3`? Don't become too fancy with macros, it obfuscates your code and makes it hard to maintain (or even unmaintainable).

Comment: moreover, what is 1 and 3? how?

Comment: i'm just showing a simplified code. I intend to make a Duff's device with some matrix operations. The same code is repeated in all the functions, only operators are different. I would like to use macros to make improvements in all the functions at the same time (one and three are just numbers (it's just an exemple))

Comment: @Skrime: The Duff's device is rather bad idea since modern compiler will do much better job of loop paralleling/unwinding.

Comment: Hmm, But that will only work for addition/subtraction. Still it looks like a bad idea. Don't use preliminary optimisation, Just use a common pattern and let the compiler optimise. Your approach might even result in worse performance. First check the output of standard code.

Comment: @Skrime: That's really interesting! I wonder if you could share your code in an answer once you get it working? Of course Olaf and Grzegorz are right that you may shoot yourself in the foot with macros and Duff's Device, but it still would be an interesting bit of code to look at.

Comment: `+` and `==` might yield different types, it is pretty unlikely you can use the same code for both variants. The same holds true for other operators as I already wrote.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski I've read so, but I just wanted to try even knowing it. The projet I'm working on works with big matrix and I have no a lot of ideas to improve the efficiency of the functions.

Comment: You may need to add additional parenthesis around your expression in the macro in order to handle operator precedence issues. For a table see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @Skrime: It's hard to say without seeing the actual code, but in general macros will not necessarily improve performance as what they do is just simple text replacement. You could check with `gcc -E` that in the end result of `OPERATION(+)` is just as you write it directly `1 + 3`, so there is no real benefit, rather than obfuscated source code.

Comment: @MichaelGeary  I edited the post so you can see what I intend to do (even if as GrzegorzSzpetkowski pointed, in modern compilers it does not improve efficiency )

Comment: Don't put parentheses around the operators in the macro definition, though.  The parentheses *do* end up in the final expansion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, almost exactly like your attempt:

```
#define OPERATION(operator) 1 operator 3
```

Comment: when I try to do this, I keep getting the following error: error: expected expression    MATRIX_OPERATION(ans[x][y++],a[x][y],b[x][y],width,height,=,*) . GCC points to the equals and to the plus symbol I Think it's caused because preprocessor would just take variable-naming-like tokens

Comment: @Skrime: Please add a real example to your question and why that is less complicated than the readable way. You might have over-simplificated.

Comment: @Skrime What is `MATRIX_OPERATION`? Show your real code.

Comment: @Skrime You added nonsensical parens. Of course `(ans[x][y++]) (=) (b[x][y]) (*) (a[x][y])` is a syntax error! (If it wasn't a syntax error, it would be undefined behavior: You're modifying and reading from `y` without an intervening sequence point.)

Comment: @melpomene at the start I did it because it solved a lot of problems, but yes, i have no excuses, that is nonsensical

Answer (score 0):

It can work but the thing is why to make your code complicated like take for example you can easily do 1+3 rather than using macros. Though appriciated for such thinking.